# Specify number of partitions for output topic when using TopologyTestDriver

Tags: testing, apache-kafka

I am using `TopologyTestDriver` when writing tests for my Kafka Streams application. Is there a way to configure the number of partitions for the `InputTestTopic` and `OutputTestTopic`?

The record process logic is quite complex in some of our applications, and it becomes even more complex when the input topics contain more than one partition. It would therefore be useful to thoroughly test the record process logic with an input topic containing more than one partition.